# Can I access Database in middleware function in _middleware.js in Next.js 12?

Tags: javascript, next.js

In Next.js 12, when I tried to connect mongodb in middleware function in _middleware.js under /pages/api/user folder, I got this error:
TypeError: **mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...).connect is not a function**
at dbConnect (webpack-internal:///./src/server/utils/dbConnect.js:39:74)
at Object.middleware [as handler] (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/api/user/_middleware.js:19:82)
at adapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/server/web/adapter.js:30:35)

part of my connection code like this:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
...
cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
     return mongoose;
});
```

So I guess that Accessing Database in _middleware.js is prohibited. Am I right?

Comment: That probably falls under the [things that aren't supported](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime#unsupported-apis) by the Edge Runtime.